# single stylesheet or numerous

Tags: css, size, loading, specs

I don't know much about speeds and all of that, so I'm not sure if a huge stylesheet would show significant changes in the loading of the page or not. To keep it simple, I want to use a stylesheet that covers all areas of the website using IDs, like #forum div.menu or #game div.menu. Knowing that this would make the stylesheet large, I'm uneasy about it being too much. Could someone provide insight on the significance of the size of a stylesheet and perhaps some specs?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4785712/338665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users are going to be using all those styles anyway, it is usually better to serve it in one stylesheet because it reduces the HTTP requests and allows the browser to cache it all. However, if you have a lot of CSS for only one page that is *not* commonly visited for your users (and it is enough that including it in the global stylesheet adds a bunch of weight and would add a substantial amount to the file), it may be better to put it in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Bigger stylesheets are better than smaller, multiple stylesheets when trying for speed. HTTP requests are one of the main reasons of slowing your webpage down. Its the same with images. One big image is far better than a lot of littler ones. Here is a good link for reducing your http requests: http://www.dailyblogtips.com/speed-up-your-site-reduce-the-http-requests/.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this Yahoo Developer Network article very useful. 
It has a number of sections regarding optimization of CSS 
for your site.

"Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site"

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html